# How to await the execution of the rds_backup_database stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

Our team is migrating one of our databases to Amazon RDS MS SQL Server. As part of that, we have to rewrite some of our stored procedures.

We have a stored procedure that performs a database backup to a network storage.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO DISK = '\\myserver\share\MydbBackup.bak'
WITH RETAINDAYS = 0,
    INIT
```

The above stored procedure is blocking i.e., it will pause the line of execution - `exec stored_proc` - until the backup is completed.

I have changed that stored procedure so that it uses the `rds_backup_database` stored proc so that the backup is saved in an S3 bucket.

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database
    @source_db_name='MyDB',
    @s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::temp-poc-bucket/db_backups/MyDBBackup.bak',
    @overwrite_s3_backup_file=1;
```

The problem is that our workflow (the stored procedure is called from our app) requires it to be synchronous.

Is there any way to "await" for the execution of the `msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database` stored procedure?

AWS RDS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/):

> When the rds_backup_database or rds_restore_database stored procedure is called, the task starts and outputs the information about the task.
>
> ...
> When the lifecycle status of the task is SUCCESS, the task is complete.
>
> ...
> You can get the Task ID after you perform the backup or restore statement. Or, you can use the following script to identify all the completed and pending tasks for a particular database:
>
> `exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='database_name'`
>
> To track the status of the job, use this SQL statement:
>
> `exec msdb..rds_task_status @task_id= 5`

So, after initiating the backup with `rds_backup_database`, you would just need to enter a loop where you use `rds_task_status` to find the current status, and if it is not "SUCCESS", you could use `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'` to sleep for 30 seconds, before continuing your loop to check status again & repeat.

There is also [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47640253/1948808) that implements a similar solution from PowerShell. Whether you implement your code in PowerShell or T-SQL, the logic for checking & looping would be similar.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. Currently checking if it is possible to stored the results of a stored proc into a temp table as it doesn't seem to be possible to filter the `rds_task_status` stored proc result directly with sql

Comment: Can anybody provide a hint on how to obtain the task_id from the rds_backup_database stored procedure using TSQL?

Comment: @DavidSnowsill That sounds like a good question to [ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Describing the problem you have & asking as a new question will give you much more visibility than asking in a comment.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73097950/3420102).